# Lenovo A2010-a keyboard

Tags: lenovo

I updated my lenovo A2010-a system and I can't unlock it cause my password is a pass code type, and the keyboard isn't working.
I already tried restarting my phone many times.
What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following fixes:

1. Fix 1: Restart the keyboard

Restarting the keyboard can be very effective in solving the problem. Many have found this to be helpful.

- Go to the Settings menu of the device
- Scroll down to the Apps section and Tap on Application Manager
- Swipe to go to the “All” tab
- Now look for the app Android Keyboard and tap on it
- Now tap on Force Stop to stop the keyboard

Exit out of the Settings menu and go back to using the keyboard and check if it works. If you happen to use a third party keyboard or if the device manufacturer has installed its own keyboard then you should look for the keyboard that is in use.

2. Fix 2: Clear Cache and Data for Keyboard

Clearing the cache and data of an application allows you to clear files that can be possibly corrupted or which may be creating problems because of bugs.

While deleting the cache files does not delete any important information, you will lose your personal settings when you delete the data files from any app.

If you had made specific changes to the keyboard, you will lose those settings. You will have to go back into the keyboard settings and make the changes once again.

- Go to the Settings menu of your device
- Tap on Application Manager which is under the apps section
- Swipe to the tab which includes “All” apps
- Now look for the keyboard app. It can be Android Keyboard or the keyboard that you are using if you have installed a third-party      keyboard or if you have the manufacturer skin on top of the stock       Android.
- Tap on the keyboard app
- Tap on Clear Cache
- Now tap on Clear Data
- Tap on OK to confirm.

  3. Fix 3:  Clear Cache and Data Files for Dictionary App

The dictionary app is closely linked with the keyboard app.

If for any reason you get the “unfortunately keyboard has stopped” error, there is a chance that it may be because of corrupt files in the dictionary app. 
Deleting these files can be helpful in solving the problem.

- Go to the Settings menu of your device
- Tap on Applications Manager
- Swipe to go to the “All” tab
- Scroll and look for Dictionary app and tap on it
- Tap on Clear Cache
- Tap on Clear Data
- Tap on OK to confirm

Once the cache and data files have been deleted, check if the problem has been fixed.

4. Fix 4: Install Updates for Google Keyboard

   You can try fixing this issue by installing updates for Google keyboard. For that, navigate to play store on your android phone and look for the updates. Alternatively download the updated Google keyboard from google play store via your PC ([Apk leecher website - can directly download the apk from Google play servers)](http://apkleecher.com/)

Acknowledgements:
[Fix Android keyboard stopped working](https://www.technobezz.com/fix-unfortunately-android-keyboard-has-stopped/)

Comment: Hello sir, thank you for your suggestion. But, i cant unlock my phone cause i need the keyboard to enter my password.

What if i use trusted devices? how do i do that?

Comment: Absolutely, you can use "trusted devices" , do you have any devices (e.g smartwatch or smartphone) you had allowed to use that feature?

Comment: Yup! I added my friends phone as a trusted device.

Comment: Great! Now you need his device to be in close range.  The lock screen security on your  device gets disabled when you are connected to a trusted via Bluetooth (your friend's device).

Comment: Lemmie know if this works, if you didn't have Bluetooth enabled, if you didn't have it active and cant access it from lockscreen, I guess you could try a workaround by installing Bluetooth toggle app, via PC using a simpler tool (android app installer or adb)